# Вывод данных в inline-клавиатуру php

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Есть следующий код, он выводит 2 кнопки в чат (Telegram-bot). Есть проблема - нужно вывести в чат inline-кнопки с товаром, который берется из бд. Каким образом это сделать? Скрипт вывода товаров из БД возвращает массив с id, названием, категорией товара. Суть проблемы - именно добавление элемента ->row в $keyboard

```
$keyboard = Keyboard::make()
->inline()
->row(
    Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Показать меню', 'callback_data' => '/show_menu']),
    Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Купить цветы', 'callback_data' => '/buyflowers'])        
);
```

Т.е. по идее, должно быть как-то так:

```
$keyboard = Keyboard::make()
->inline()
foreach ($products as $product) {
    ->(['text' => '$p[название товара]', 'callback_data' => 'товар$p[id]']),       
}     
);
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: в чём проблема-то?

Comment: @Anatol проблема в том, что блок foreach нельзя вставить в массив, как правильно это сделать? Нужно создать функцию в классе Keyboard, которая будет добавлять row в уже существующую клавиатуру?

Comment: начнём с того, что клавиатура - это массив. разве нельзя сначала создать массив, а потом в цикле его наполнить? пхп не знаю просто